# How to get the size of UIActivityViewController popoverPresentationController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

How Can I get the size of the UIActivityViewController popoverPresentationController?

[image]

Comment: Are you not setting the pop over size before displaying it or do you want to know the default size of the pop over?

Comment: @Satyam Yes, I'm not setting the pop over size before displaying it...